# Raspberry pi does not show up in bubbleupnp

Tags: wifi, pi-3, streaming, alsa, media-server

After following this post - http://blog.scphillips.com/posts/2013/07/playing-music-on-a-raspberry-pi-using-upnp-and-dlna-revisited/

Raspberry pi would not show up in the bubbleupnp rendered list.
After configuring gmrender, I installed the app in android running kitkat, but in the renderer list it only shows "Local media render".
How to diagnose this?

*PS - Goal - Simply stream mp3 files in the phone to raspberry pi.*
*PPS - I have assumed when I power the PI and login, I would just need to open the app, connect and stream music.*

**EDIT**

running this `./src/gmediarender -f "My Renderer"`

results

```
gmediarender 0.0.7-git started [ gmediarender 2016-10-22_57dfbfd (libupnp-1.6.19+git20141001; glib-2.42.1; gstreamer-1.4.4) ].
Logging switched off. Enable with --logfile=<filename> (e.g. --logfile=/dev/stdout for console)
gmediarender: output_gstreamer.c:503: output_gstreamer_init: Assertion `player_ != ((void *)0)' failed.
Aborted
```

What does this mean? Is this to be ignored if you go by the tutorial blog post setup.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem here with my orangepi boad.

It was fixed by installing manually all the `gstreamer1.0-*` binary dependencies suggested in the blog post you linked.

I also had to change some parameters in `/etc/default/gmediarender`:

```
ENABLED=1
DAEMON_USER="pi"
```

If it still does not work try with a fixed IP:

```
DAEMON_EXTRA_ARGS="-I 192.168.42.79"
```

Comment: I would keep this in my knowledge base. I got it to work simply by rebooting and reconfiguring the wifi settings in my router as well. I don't know how it worked but later when trying on another SD card, instructions from the blog worked straight up 1st time.